# Clueless about this error: Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I'm building a Chrome extension so I can get some hands on ECMASCript 6, but I'm getting this error on my events page:

`Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined`

I'm using browserify + babelify to transform my code.

This is the events page: (**alarm.js**):

```
import ScrapperAlarm from './scrapper_alarm';
import {ALARMS} from '../config/const';

export default class Alarm {
    constructor( chrome_alarm ) {
        this.chrome_alarm = chrome_alarm;
    }

    run() {
        console.log( 'Alarm << %s >> run()', this.chrome_alarm.name );
    }

    static loadByChromeAlarm( chrome_alarm ) {
        switch( chrome_alarm.name ) {
            case ALARMS.SCRAPPER:
                return new ScrapperAlarm( chrome_alarm );
                break;
        }
    }
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener( ( chrome_alarm ) => {
    alarm.loadByChromeAlarm( chrome_alarm ).run(); 
} );

chrome.alarms.create( ALARMS.SCRAPPER, { periodInMinutes: 1 } );
```

ScrapperAlarm is defined as: (**scrapper_alarm.js**)

```
import Alarm from './alarm';
import Scrapper from '../scrapper/scrapper';

class ScrapperAlarm extends Alarm {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    run() {
        super.run();
        this.scrapper = new Scrapper();
        this.scrapper.run();
    }
}

export default ScrapperAlarm;
```

Debugging the error, it seems it's happening here:

```
var ScrapperAlarm = (function (_Alarm) {
    _inherits(ScrapperAlarm, _Alarm); // <-- ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

I'm not sure how to go from here; any help is appreciated.

Comment: You've got a circular dependency here. If you load `alarm.js` first, it will load `scrapper_alarm.js`, and in there the `Alarm` binding will not yet have a value.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, this was indeed what happened!

Comment: @Bergi, please add your comment as an Answer so that it can be accepted to close out this question.

Comment: Got a similar error, had forgotten to `export default` the base class, leading to the value of the base class being `{}`.